# How can I pass a function's output to a different function as input?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I'm trying to write a function which gets as parameters a list of functions, and parameters for the first one. It then calls them in order, passing the output of the previous one into the next one. (Obviously for this to work all functions must expect the same number of parameters and return the same number of values).

Here's what I tried:

```
def chain(functions, *first_func_params):
    params = first_func_params
    for func in functions:
        params = func(*params)
```

However this works only if all the functions return tuples ('multiple values') or other sequence types, because only sequence types can be unpacked into the parameter list of a function.

If the functions simply return single values, `chain` doesn't work.

I *could* simply check if `func`'s output is a tuple or not and act accordingly. But is there a more elegant solution?

How would you implement this?

Comment: I think my advice would be to not write this function :-).  There are too many corner cases that could end up really surprising.  e.g. You pass `[foo, bar]`, and `foo` returns a `namedtuple` (which `bar` expects as input) -- Unfortunately, the pipeline fails because your function composition decided to _unpack the namedtuple_ when it should have just passed the argument through.

Comment: can you make your functions expect a single tuple as input `f(t)`, so that it can manually unpack the parameters like `a,b,c = t`? Then the return value should also be a tuple in any case (e.g. `return (True, )`). That way no special cases are needed

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
if not isinstance(params, tuple):
    params = (params,)
```

Or catch the `TypeError` exception that will be raised if you try to use `*` before an unpackable object.

Comment: I could do that. But is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @AvivCohn For me that's elegant, I'm afraid I can't think another way of doing it...